# What's wrong with this equation (Newton's Third Law & Energy Conservative Principle)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

In an elastic collision, the energy is conserved. So

$$
KE_{1} = KE_{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}m_1\vec u_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2\vec u_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_1\vec v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2\vec v_2^2 \\
-m_2 (\vec v_2^2 - \vec u_2^2) = m_1 (\vec v_1^2 - \vec u_1^2)
\\ -m_2(2 \vec a_2 \vec s_2) = m_1(2 \vec a_1 \vec s_1)
\\ - \vec F_2 \vec S_2 = \vec F_1 \vec S_1
$$ From  Newton's 3rd law: $-\vec F_2=\vec F_1$
$$
\\ \vec S_2 = \vec S_1
$$
But after testing it out in simulator([Link](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/collision-lab/latest/collision-lab_en.html)), It's wrong. 
Which step is wrong?

Comment: How did you test your result with the simulation in your link? It is not so detailed to show what happens during collision. You would need something to show the deformation of the bodies during the collision, which I don't see here. You realize that S1, S2 are diplacement of the contact point during the collision, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

The equation you appear to be using, namely $$v^2=u^2+2as$$ is used for systems with constant acceleration. Hence, this would not apply to a collision where the force involved is impulsive.

What you're doing is essentially stating that from the above equation, since $$v^2-u^2=2aS\implies m(v^2-u^2)=2m\cdot a\cdot S\\
\rightarrow m(v^2-u^2)\propto F\cdot dS$$

In a collision, contact forces are not constant. This is why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deduce $\vec{S}_1=\vec{S}_2$ from $\vec{F}_1\cdot\vec{S}_1=\vec{F}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2$. You can reshape the equation as $\vec{F}_1\cdot(\vec{S}_1-\vec{S}_2)=\vec{0}$, which yields that $\vec{S}_1-\vec{S}_2$ is perpendicular to $\vec{F}_1$. It does not have to vanish though, we have only elliminated one direction. Therefore on a more basic level, you could also point out the error in that you are taking one equation ($\vec{F}_1\cdot\vec{S}_1=\vec{F}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2$) about the entries of the vectors $\vec{S}_1$ and $\vec{S}_2$ and then conclude three equations ($\vec{S}_1=\vec{S}_2$) out of them.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The equation: $$v_f^2 - v_i^2 = 2a_x (x_f-x_i)$$
only applies when the acceleration is uniform. This is not the case for collisions, elastic or not, because the impulsive force is usually not constant, and vanishes after the collision.

(2) You have used vector symbols throughout the simplifications, but kinetic energy is a scalar, and $v$ in $K = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$ is the *speed*, also a scalar.

Hope this helps.